# Adding a project reference incorrectly adds a dll reference

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, xaf

I have just updated VS2017 and VS2019 vs and upgraded my projects to reference .Net Framework 4.7.2

When I open my c# XAF winforms solution I get build errors.

```
 CS0246: The type or namespace name could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference
```

As though the reference to the Module project was missing.

The reference is the file referenced is in  the folder
  MyApp\Module\bin\Debug\MyApp.Module.dll

When I delete the reference and attempt to add the project, a reference to the .dll adds instead.

I am using Nuget for the XAF dlls

I can see the following in MyApp.Module.Win.csproj

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyApp.Module\MyApp.Module.csproj">
      <Project>{guid etc}</Project>
      <Name>MyApp.Module</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
```

Comment: maybe the issue is due to needing to update  the nuget packages to use a different target framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had missed upgrading one of the projects to .Net Framework 4.7.2
I fixed that.
Now the solution builds.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. You can consider marking it as answer:)